# Time and date data on x-Axis in Python

Tags: python, plot, raspberry-pi, sensors

ON the Raspberry PI 4, I read out a sensor (via HAT) and write the dataset into a .csv file. At the same time, I write for every single value the time and date into the next column. 
How do I plot these datas?
I want to set the x axis as the time axis, so eg. at 11:23:48 I measured 4,3 V.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import sys
import warnings
if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

root = Tk()
root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename ( initialdir = "/home/pi", title = "Datei auswählen", filetypes = (("Comma Seperated Values (CSV)", "*.csv"), ("Alle Dateien", "*.*")) )

df = pd.read_csv(root.filename, delimiter = '\t', decimal = ',')
# pressure = df.loc [:, "Chan 0"]
temp = df.loc [:, "Chan 0 "]
df["Uhrzeit"] = df["Uhrzeit"].astype("str")
time = df.loc [:, "Uhrzeit"]
temp_echt = (52.2357*temp)-100.0001
# plt.figure (1)
# plt.plot (pressure, lw = 0.8)
plt.figure (2)
plt.ylabel ('Temperatur [°C]')
plt.plot(time,temp_echt, lw = 1)
plt.xticks (rotation = 45)
print (time)
plt.show()
```

Output:[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp7Eq.png)

So what is going on here, why does the plot look so weird?
Btw: this is the csv file:[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQgBw.png)

Answer (score 0):

The plot looks right to me. You have multiple same times and same Chan 0's, thats why multiple lines are over each other. It looks indeed weird. You could try to take only one Chan 0 per same time or just wait until you have more data, it should look more and more alright with the time.

Comment: Is there any possibility to plot the time data for example every 10 minutes? So, I record an acceleration-sensor for 4 hours, but on the x axis I just want to update the time every 10 minutes?

Comment: Of course, if 'times' and 'temp_echt' are lists you can do the following:

```times = times[::10]                              
times_echt = times_echt[::10]
```
the lists contain now jsut every 10th element